# How to sketch a graphs for Fourier series coefficients

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> I'm struggling to plot the correct Fourier series graph for the following function when $n = 1, n = 1.5$ and $n = 2.5.$
>   $$y = 5 + 20 \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1 - \cos(n \pi)}{\pi^2 n^2}\cdot{\cos(\pi / t)\cdot nt}$$

Comment: What's $t$ supposed to be?

Answer (score 2):

The fourier coefficients are a function $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, as in your case.
They are not defined for fractional $n$. I suggest you use a bar chart or simply dots at integer evaluation-points.